# pip install psycopg2 not working

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

After trying everything mentioned on the posts I could find about this same issue, I have yet to have any luck installing psycopg2

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH

or specify the full executable path with the option:

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
```

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

Comment: What kind of setup do you have? Can you install anything else with pip?

Comment: On Ubuntu, I first install PostgreSQL w/ "sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev" and then simply run "pip install psycopg2". On RHEL, it's "sudo yum install postgresql9-server"

Comment: I am using OSX, pip install works for everything else, and I have the postgres.app installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pg_config is in /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin. So you need to add that directory to your PATH in ~/.bash_profile:

```
PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: You might want to do `locate pg_config` to find where it is and add to path